# What does * mean in linux directory listing

Tags: linux

I'm looking at a flask app and when I perform

```
ls -la
```

I see:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername  770 Nov 17 20:03 alembic.ini
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername  346 Nov 17 20:03 bower.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername 8192 Nov 17 20:03 dev.db
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername myusername  358 Nov 21 11:07 dispatch.fcgi*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername 2158 Nov 17 20:03 env.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername myusername 2651 Nov 21 11:04 manage.py*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername myusername 3058 Nov 22 17:26 manage_apache.fcgi*
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 3012 Nov 22 12:17 manage_apache.py
drwxrwxr-x 8 myusername myusername 4096 Nov 17 21:05 myflaskapp/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername  511 Nov 17 20:03 orequirements.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername  789 Nov 17 20:03 pets.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername  713 Nov 22 11:17 requirements.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername  412 Nov 17 20:03 script.py.mako
```

dispatch.fcgi:

```
import sys,os
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/myusername/....')
print(str(sys.path))
from myflaskapp.settings import Config, SharedConfig
from myflaskapp.app import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app(SharedConfig)
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

what does the `*` in dispatch.fcgi* mean

Comment: it means executable.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from `man ls`:

> ```
> -F, --classify
>               append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
> ```

These are indicators appended to filenames according to their type

1. `*` for executable
2. `/` for directory
3. `|` for pipe

etc

Answer (score 1):

It already has an answer on [SuperUser's What does the asterisk mean after a filename if you do ls -l](https://superuser.com/a/178808).

As mentioned in [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer](https://superuser.com/a/178789), it means that the file is executable. A classifier is shown when `-F` is passed to `ls` via the command line or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You might notice that each file with an * following its name is also a file with execute permissions set.

Answer (score 1):

They are executable files, meaning the +x bit is set.
Use `ls --classify` to get these indicators after file names.